# Is there a theorem relates continuity of x-section&y-section of a function and continuity(measurability) of a function itself?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(X,\tau),(Y,T),(Z,O)$be topological spaces.

Let $f:X\times Y\rightarrow Z$ be a function.

Let $f_x,f^y$ denote $x,y$-section of $f$ respectively.

Let's assume $f_x,f^y$ are continuous for all $x,y$.

Then what information about $f$ would these hypothesis imply?

This does not imply neither $f$ is continuous nor measurable.